# How to include or exclude an attribute from the HTML in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using angular 4 with angular materials to construct a table.
I want the `mat-sort-header` to be added conditionally on the following template.

```
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</mat-header-cell>
```

I have tried the following code:

```
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [mat-sort-header]=" column!='id' ? column : false ">Id</mat-header-cell>
```

But it still adds the sorting header in the table for this column.

My overall table looks as follows, and is working fine, except for the sorting header issue:

```
  <mat-table #table1 [dataSource]="records" matSort class="mat-cell">

    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of keys" [matColumnDef]="column">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [mat-sort-header]=" column!='actions' ? column : false ">
        <p *ngIf=" column!='actions' ">{{ column }}</p>
        <button *ngIf=" column=='actions' " mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="functionA()">
          <mat-icon class="indigo-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">add</mat-icon>
        </button>

      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i=index;">
        <p *ngIf=" column!='actions' ">{{ row[column] }}</p>
        <button *ngIf=" column=='actions' " mat-icon-button color="accent" (click)="functionA()">
          <mat-icon class="indigo-icon" aria-label="Edit">edit</mat-icon>
        </button>

        <button *ngIf=" column=='actions' " mat-icon-button color="accent" (click)="functionA()">
          <mat-icon class="indigo-icon" aria-label="Delete">delete</mat-icon>
        </button>

      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="keys"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: keys;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, I solved it as follow:

```
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [mat-sort-header]=" column!='actions' ? column : null " [disabled]=" column=='actions' ? true : false " >
```

Needed to bind the `disabled` property.

Comment: Only the `[disabled]` will do it. No need to remove the `mat-sort-header` conditionally as in a lot of cases breaks sorting

Comment: And thanks a ton for this. I broke my head so many hours till I found out finally another person with this issue. :-)

Comment: Karma test will fail in this case : how do you solve this: If 'mat-header-cell' is an Angular component and it has 'disabled' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: In fact, I added MatSortModule in the test and it worked. Sorry about that :)

Comment: Only adding the `[disabled]` attribute only disables it, but still shows the controls.
It seems it is not possible to completely remove the sorting controls from just one column

Answer (score 10):

CoderX's answer is the best approach for your question. but there might come a scenario where you need to render a separate template based on condition.
In such a case you can do it like below:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="columnAction=='sort'; else noSort">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header />          
</ng-container>

<ng-template #noSort>
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef />         
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me to disable mat sort for a specific columns !!

```
<ng-container *ngIf="tableData == 'deviceState' || tableData == 'firmwareVersion' || tableData == 'edge'; else noSort">
    <th scope="col" *matHeaderCellDef matSortDisabled> {{getHeader(tableData)}} </th>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #noSort>
    <th scope="col" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{getHeader(tableData)}} </th>
</ng-template>
```